# Problem libOpenni2 for hydro installation with homebrew

Tags: ros, openni2-camera, mac

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I try to install ROS Hydro on my mac with homebrew following this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source
And I face a problem. For the installation of openni2_camera, I have the following error.

```
-- Found PkgConfig: /opt/local/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.28")
-- checking for module 'libopenni2'
--   package 'libopenni2' not found
CMake Error at /opt/local/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:341 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/local/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:395 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (pkg_check_modules)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Of course I installed openni2 via hombrew but it seems like it doesn't create any libopenni2.pc which is a problem.

Any ideas about it ?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

This is the result of *brew info openni2*

```
openni2: stable 2.2.0.33, HEAD
http://structure.io/openni
/usr/local/Cellar/openni2/2.2.0.33 (149 files, 6,8M) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/openni2.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: libusb ✔
==> Options
--universal
    Build a universal binary
--with-docs
    Build documentation using javadoc (might fail with Java 1.8)
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
Add the recommended variables to your dotfiles.
 * On Bash, add them to `~/.bash_profile`.
 * On Zsh, add them to `~/.zprofile` instead.

export OPENNI2_INCLUDE=/usr/local/include/ni2
export OPENNI2_REDIST=/usr/local/lib/ni2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201259/problem-libopenni2-for-hydro-installation-with-homebrew/) by [kpax77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21348/kpax77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2015-01-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

The Hydro version of openni2_camera does not handle well libopenni2 on mac. You should edit the file *openni2_camera/CMakeLists.txt* and change this line:

```
pkg_check_modules(PC_OPENNI2 REQUIRED libopenni2)
```

for this:

```
pkg_check_modules(PC_OPENNI2 libopenni2)
if (NOT PC_OPENNI2_FOUND)
  pkg_check_modules(PC_OPENNI2 REQUIRED openni2)
endif()
```

(This patch is already present on Indigo)

**UPDATE**

According to the result of *brew info openni2*, could you try to add the following two lines to your *~/.bash_profile* file

```
export OPENNI2_INCLUDE=/usr/local/include/ni2
export OPENNI2_REDIST=/usr/local/lib/ni2
```

then restart your terminal. If it doesn't work try uninstalling openni2 (you currently installed it from the formula https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/openni2.rb) and try installing it again, but this time using the formula at https://github.com/ros/homebrew-deps/blob/master/openni2.rb.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2015-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kpax77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21348/kpax77/) on 2015-01-20**:
Thank you. I did it and I have the same problem now it doesn't find openni2.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2015-01-20**:
Can you post the result of the command "brew info openni2"?

**Comment by [kpax77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21348/kpax77/) on 2015-01-21**:
Now it almost compiled everything but it doesn't find the linux/usbdevice_fs.h:

/Users/skynet/ros_catkin_ws/src/openni2_camera/src/usb_reset.c:40:10: fatal error: 'linux/usbdevice_fs.h' file not found
#include <linux/usbdevice_fs.h>
^
1 error generated.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-08-11**:
This worked for Indigo installation on my OSX 10.10 too. Key for me was restarting the terminal after doing `export OPENNI2_*`.